# neo4j apoc - extraneous input '('

Tags: collections, neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

what am I doing wrong with the query

```
WITH [1] AS a, [2] AS b
RETURN apoc.coll.union(a,b);
```

Although it returns the result (`[1,2]`) In the browser it keeps telling me `extraneous input '(', expecting...`

Is this a problem or just "Lint garbage"? I am trying to identify a problem with another query where the same Lint message pops up in the same kind of use of the apoc function.

Comment: Sounds like you should add this as a [neo4j browser issue](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-browser/issues). Good that it executes fine, but definitely something to clean up.

Comment: It looks like an issue with the union word. I just tried this: WITH [1] AS a, [2] AS b
RETURN apoc.coll.unionAll(a,b);  and It does not complain.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**

As discussed in the comments, `CALL` is not appropriate to functions (like `apoc.coll.union`). So I believe this behavior is a bug in the lint of Neo4j Browser. I opened [an issue](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-browser/issues/638) in the Neo4j Browser repo.

**ORIGINAL ANSWER:**

I believe the problem is that a user defined procedure (like `apoc.coll.union`) should be called with [CALL](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/call/) and not after the `RETURN` statement. You can try something like:

```
WITH [1] AS a, [2] AS b
CALL apoc.coll.union(a,b) as r
RETURN r
```

Comment: thanks! that still doesn't seem to do the job though. its the same message again, this time at the `as r`. see [screenshot](http://imgur.com/a/ax5FV)

Comment: This is a function, and not a procedure in the recent APOC, so CALL is not appropriate here.

Comment: @tscherg I believe this is a bug in neo4j browser and opened a issue in the github repo as shown in my edit. Thanks!